# R: Error with Nelder-Mead optimization to select starting values

Tags: r, optimization, mixed-models, nonlinear-optimization

The data can be found [here](https://www.stat.ubc.ca/~lang/Stat527a/aids.dat2)

```
library(nlme)
library(dfoptim)
dat0 <- read.table("aids.dat2",head=T)
dat1 <- dat0[dat0$day<=90, ]   # use only first 90-day data
dat2 <- dat1[!apply(is.na(dat1),1,any),]  # remove missing data 
aids.dat <- groupedData(lgcopy ~ day | patid, data=dat2)
aids.dat$log10copy = log10(aids.dat$lgcopy)

myfun2 <- function(arg){
  s.p1 <- arg[1]
  s.b1 <- arg[2]
  s.p2 <- arg[3]
  s.b2 <- arg[4]
  model = nlme(log10copy ~ exp(p1-b1*day) + exp(p2-b2*day),
               fixed = list(p1 ~ 1, b1 ~ 1, p2 ~ 1, b2 ~ 1),
               random = list(patid = pdDiag(list(p1 ~ 1, b1 ~ 1, p2 ~ 1, b2 ~ 1))),
               start = list(fixed = c(p1 = s.p1, b1 = s.b1, p2 = s.p2, b2 = s.b2)),
               data =aids.dat) 
  return(model$logLik)
}

nmkb(fn = myfun2, par = c(10,0.5,6,0.005), lower = c(5, 0.1, 5, 0.001), upper = c(15, 1, 10, 0.1))
```

Running the above code, I run into several errors:

```
Error in nlme.formula(log10copy ~ exp(p1 - b1 * day) + exp(p2 - b2 * day),  : 
  step halving factor reduced below minimum in PNLS step
In addition: Warning message:
In nlme.formula(log10copy ~ exp(p1 - b1 * day) + exp(p2 - b2 * day),  :
  Singular precision matrix in level -1, block 1
```

The model fits fine with the staring values from `par = c(10,0.5,6,0.005)`. However, I think as the random algorithm starts using other starting values in `lower = c(5, 0.1, 5, 0.001), upper = c(15, 1, 10, 0.1)` the `nlme` call runs into the above problems because it's so sensitive to starting values. As a result, the `nmkb` call never amounts to anything.

Is there a way to circumvent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model log-liklihood needs to be maximized, but many optimization procedures in R gives minimization result. So the function to be optimized has to be the negative log-likelihood. So it should look like this:

```
myfun2 <- function(arg){
  s.p1 <- arg[1]
  s.b1 <- arg[2]
  s.p2 <- arg[3]
  s.b2 <- arg[4]
  model = nlme(log10copy ~ exp(p1-b1*day) + exp(p2-b2*day),
               fixed = list(p1 ~ 1, b1 ~ 1, p2 ~ 1, b2 ~ 1),
               random = list(patid = pdDiag(list(p1 ~ 1, b1 ~ 1, p2 ~ 1, b2 ~ 1))),
               start = list(fixed = c(p1 = s.p1, b1 = s.b1, p2 = s.p2, b2 = s.b2)),
               data =aids.dat) 
  return(-model$logLik)
}
```

And although there are still many warnings, there is no more error on my machine, and the algorithm converges successfully.

```
$par
[1] 13.460199068  0.848526199  7.764024099  0.001513636

$value
[1] -358.6631

$feval
[1] 197

$restarts
[1] 0

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "Successful convergence"

Warning messages:
1: In nlme.formula(log10copy ~ exp(p1 - b1 * day) + exp(p2 - b2 * day),  :
  Singular precision matrix in level -1, block 1
```